# How to call non-static method from static method in an aspx.cs code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind, static-methods, object-reference

A similar question was asked elsewhere, but the answer doesn't seem to work in my particular situation. 
I have a hidden field on an aspx page:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="dataReceiver" runat="server" Value="" />
```

I'm trying to access this field from the codebehind. It seems like I have to reference it from within the default class that's automatically generated by VS2010. Since I can't create a new class I tried the following.

```
1public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
2{
3   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
4   {
5       Data2();
6       MessageBox.Show(dataReceiver.Value);
7   }

8   public void Data1()
9   {
10      dataReceiver.Value = "123456";
11  }

12  public static void Data2()
13  {
14      _Default def = new _Default();
15      def.Data1();
16  }
17}
```

This generates an error at Line 10: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I've also tried typing Line 14 as "_Default def = new _Default().Data1();" but this is rejected by the compiler with an error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'WebApplication6._Default'"

Is there a way to make this work, or do I need a completely different approach?

[EDIT]
Darin's response below resolved this for me, but it did take me a little while to figure out how to apply the information. I thought I should clarify the details of the solution in case anyone reads this later with a similar problem.
Although the WebMethod can't call an instance method, and it doesn't seem to be able to access elements of the page regardless of their "runat" attribute, it can return a value to the JavaScript method calling it. The value will be accessible in the JavaScript as a local variable called "result" which is passed to the "success" or "failure" functions.

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<asp:ScriptManager id="scriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods= "true" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="dataReceiver" runat="server" Value="789" />
</asp:Content>
//Javascript
function callServer() {
    PageMethods.Data2($("#MainContent_dataReceiver").attr("value").toString(), success, failure);

    function success(result, userContext, methodName) { alert(result + " . " + userContext + " . " + methodName); }
    function failure(result, userContext, methodName) { alert(result + " . " + userContext + " . " + methodName); }
}
//C# Code Behind
[WebMethod]
public static string Data2(string value)
{
    value = "101112";
    return value;
}
```

Comment: What does the `@Page` directive on the `.aspx` page where you have this control look like?

Comment: Why don't you call Data1 directly from the Page_Load method?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque - because you need an instance of a class to call Data1.

Comment: @JonH, in the Page_Load method, you're already in an instance of _Default...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque True, I dont know the intent of what the OP is after, just as confused.

Comment: @BrandonRoss, btw, showing a MessageBox from ASP.NET code-behind doesn't make sense... the MessageBox will show on the server, not the client, and it will block the request processing

Comment: @Oded - "<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication6._Default" %>"

Comment: @Thomas & JonH - This example is a reproduction of a problem that I'm having in a larger program. To show you the whole thing I'd have to post about 500 lines of code. In a nutshell, I need to be able to call the function after the page has already been loaded.

Comment: @Thomas - The messagebox is just for debugging purposes. It shows up for me just fine when published to "localhost". I'm not about to publish this example anywhere else, so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: My intent here is to be able to change the value of the hidden input at will, rather than just at Page_Load. The static method is called as a page method from a line of javascript code. I'm trying to send data back to the client from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access instance fields from a [PageMethod](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) in ASP.NET which I suspect is what you are trying to achieve here. That's how it is and there's not much you could do about it. So what I would recommend you is to simply have your page method take the value of the hidden field as argument:

```
public static void Data2(string value)
{
    ... do something with the value of the hidden field
}
```

Now let the caller of the page method supply the required value since it is in the context of the page.

Comment: No kidding. I thought I had been more clear, but I definitely forgot to include a couple details.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what's going on here - what you're trying to achieve. You're receiving the error because presumably the parameterless constructor for `_Default` doesn't set `dataReceiver` to a useful value.

Is there any reason why `Data2()` *needs* to be a static method? What should it *logically* be calling `Data1()` on? You shouldn't just decide that because you need to call `Data1()` on *some* instance, that it's okay to just create a new instance of `_Default` and call it on that. Work out the logical *purpose* of the call, and that should indicate which instance you need to call `Data1()` on - or whether this should actually be an instance method to start with.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jon. Data2 needs to be static because in my original program that I pulled this code from it is a WebMethod. I apologize for failing to mention that in my original post...

Comment: @BrandonRoss: If it's a `WebMethod`, why would it need to refer to an instance of the page? That page doesn't exist, logically. It sounds like that's a fundamental problem in your design - ignore the implementation for the moment, and think about the *logical* design.

Comment: I can understand the value of good design, yet this is far from being the only potential design flaw in the project that I'm working on. I'm still learning and don't have a master programmer holding my hand through the process. Eventually I'll go back and refactor the whole thing on my own free-time if I have to. I'll definitely keep your advice in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a new instance: `_Default def = new _Default();`, to access it use `dataReceiver.Value`.  If a control specifies `runat=server` it means you can access the control from within code behind.

Why is `Data1` an instance method?  We need more information.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jon.
dataReceiver is unavailable within Data2() -- I'm guessing because it is static. It is available within Data1(), but causes a runtime error if Data1 is called from Data2. 
I'm not sure I can answer for why Data1 is an instance method. All I want to do is alter the value of dataReceiver after the page has been loaded, say, when the user clicks on something, for example.